# Create a binary tree from a Stack?

Tags: c, data-structures, tree

I'm tasked with creating a program that turns something like `((X+3)*(X+4))` into a binary tree, along with some other features. So far, I have taken in the input, and parsed it into two stacks, one containing the operands, the other the operators.

I defined the stacks simply for now (so they only have a nextnode and `char value`.
However, I seem to have problems adding values from the stacks into my tree (so probably a problem in defining the tree).

My stack is defined as such:

```
typedef struct node
{
    char value;
    struct node * nextnode;
} node;
```

My tree is defined:

```
typedef struct tree
{
    node * thisNode;
    struct tree *right, *left;
} tree;
```

I'm not sure about the node* part, perhaps it should be something different.

I've been considering the simple case of 2+3 for starters. In this case, the root of the tree should be +, with left being 2 and right being 3.

```
 +
/\
2 3
```

How to add something that's on a stack to my tree?  I have tried using

```
root->thisNode = operatorTop;
```

Where operatorTop is the top of the operator stack (defined as `node * operatorTop`),
but even that simple line seems to segfault.

Comment: You'll have to show us a complete program that segfaults. There's nothing inherently wrong with your data structures (other than that you're using a char for an int and you're typedefing named structs, which isn't exactly incorrect).

Comment: Thats pretty much all I was asking, is if there was something inherently wrong. I forget to label it, but this is homework, so I don't want /too/ much help. Hogan got me on the right track, it was exactly that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe the problem is you have not called `malloc()` to reserve the space for `root`.

(Compilers will report null pointer assignment, but segfault on null point dereference because you are pointing to a random place.)

Comment: Thanks! that was it exactly. I knew it was something simple.