# Parse stack into a binary tree?

Tags: c, data-structures, tree, stack

I'm making a program tasked with converting a math expression such as `(2+4)*(4/3)` into
a binary tree, and then manipulating it.

First, when parsing, i've turned the string into two stacks, operands and operators. 
How can I determine what the root should be, given that in my example above the tree should look like this:

```
     *
    / \
   +   /
   /\  /\
  2 4  4 3
```

Notice that the root is * which is the outermost operand. But on my operand stack it looks like this:

```
/
*
+
```

And there could be cases like `(2+4+3)*4` or `2*((4+1)/3)`.

How can I determine which operand should be the root of my binary tree?

Comment: Does the parser understand the rules of precedence, or are you always using brackets to force it?

Comment: I have to create a parser as well (so far i just have it sorting between operands and operators, and keeping track of brackets). But yes, the brackets will always be there (no rules of precedence).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a Binary Tree from a Stack?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149437/create-a-binary-tree-from-a-stack)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert your infix expression to either prefix or postfix notation. You can't really have a proper operator stack without doing this.

In postfix notation, the expression `(2+4)*(4/3)` would look like:

```
2 4 + 4 3 / *
```

So, you have the multiplication appearing at the end which could be inserted into the tree as its root. Evaluating a postfix expression is much easier for a computer as grouping is not needed.

Comment: Ah, thankyou. I forgot I had to turn it into postfix. That would make things much easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just put the operators on your stack in the order that they appear in your expression.  Once you've done that, you lose the ability to disambiguate, as you've identified.

See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting_yard_algorithm for an algorithm to parse infix notation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a stack to implement an infix to binary expression tree. This link has a C++ implementation:

[An infix to binary-expression-tree parser that usings two stacks](http://cplusplus.kurttest.com/notes/stack.html#binary-expression-tree)

one for operators and another for operands, which all derive from a base node class.